# Run Time Error in finding the probability of prime distance between two nodes of tree

Tags: c

***Intro to problem***
You are given a tree. If we select 2 distinct nodes uniformly at random, what's the probability that the distance between these 2 nodes is a prime number?
**Input**
The first line contains a number N: the number of nodes in this tree.
The following N-1 lines contain pairs `a[i]` and `b[i]`, which means there is an edge with length 1 between `a[i]` and `b[i]`.
**Output**
Output a real number denote the probability we want.
You'll get accept if the difference between your answer and standard answer is no more than 10^-6.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
int checkprime(int d);
int fact(int m);
void main()
{
    int N, i, j, f, p = 0, t, d, x, y, z;
    float result;
    int a[49999], b[49999];
    printf("Enter the number of nodes\n");
    scanf("%d", &N);
    printf("\n");
    for (i = 0; i < N - 1; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d\t%d", &a[i], &b[i]);//Inputting the nodes
    }
    for (i = 0; i < N - 1; i++)
    {
        for (j = i; j < N - 1; j++)
        {
            d = b[j] - a[i];//Taking distance between nodes
            f = checkprime(d);//Checking if it is prime
            if (f == 1)
            {
                p = p + 1;//If found prime,then increasing the number of 
                          //possibilities
            }
        }
    }
    x = fact(N);
    y = fact(2);
    z = fact(N - 2);
    y = y * z;
    t = x / y;//finding C(N,2).Combination of number of nodes and pair of 2
    result = p / t;//finding probability
    printf("\n\n%f", result);

}
int checkprime(int d)//function to check prime
{
    int k, flag = 1;
    for (k = 2; k < d / 2; k++)
    {
        if (d % k == 0)
        {
            flag = 0;
        }
    }
    return flag;
}
int fact(int m)//function to calculate factorial
{
    int k, r = 1;
    for (k = m; k > 1; k--)
    {
        r = r * k;
    }
    return r;
}
```

Comment: How big can `N` be? 50000?

Comment: The range of N is between 0 to 50000

Comment: Consider this: Let N=5 and the entries will be a[i]=1,2,3,4 b[i]=2,3,4,5.So the output should be 0.5 as the total combinations will be 10 and the possibilities of prone distance will be 5.so 5/10 is 0.5